Extruding a face causes glossy or seemingly smooth-shaded faces where there shouldn't be
I was practicing in Blender 4.1 by making some simple shapes and texturing them. An example is this slab shown in material preview and solid mode. I noticed when extruding one of its faces, the shading looks slightly different than the rest.

I tried to go into Object mode, right-click the object and select Shade Flat, and it returns the shading to 'normal'. The reverse is also true, if I select Shade Smooth, the shading appears again. However, if I apply Shade Smooth to other objects I already made, expecting them to also have the shading problem, they remain the same, so I'm not sure if this is the proper way to do it. In the image below you can see that the original slab retains the same shading 'look', regardless if I selected smooth or flat.

I've made a few things so far, and this hasn't happened yet, or I never noticed before. Maybe I clicked a setting or did something to make this default behavior, but I don't know the keywords to search for to try and fix it myself. Does anyone know what might be happening?

The new edges are not marked sharp when you extrude them. Thats why I prefer to add a AutoSmooth modifier instead of using Shade Smooth by Angle. Otherwise you're gonna have to constantly be remarking it sharp. The modifier does it procedurally.

I would also recommend changing your default edge color in your theme to something a little different so you can see the difference between sharp/non-sharp edges.

Ooh, I didn't know that, thanks! However, if I make a new project this behavior isn't happening though. But it made me think, could it have something to do with having opened a file that wasn't made in Blender 4.1?

No I don't think its a bug from switching versions, though that probably isn't helping. But it's expected behavior that the extruded geo might not match the sharp edges from the base mesh. That's why I like the modifier, not manually setting it.
